# Deploy ASPNET website with iis and rds as sqlserver with cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have aspnet webdeploy package(.zip) now i want it to deploy in AWS with cloudformation.

my cloudformation should contain

vpc with two subnet (private and public)

Private subnet will contain Instance and RDS(sqlserver web or any)
Public Subnet will have NAT, Bastian host (for login into actual instance) and internet gateway.

Cloudformation should pick appication(zip) from s3 URL.
and at the end as output i can get URL (working website).

anyhelp would be really appreciated (if someone has cloudformation which do the same please post it here or send me on **kotnala.ajayk@gmail.com**)

Thanks,

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have requirements to use CloudFormation directly, I would recommend using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and the AWS Console to setup your VPC and deploy your application. Using the AWS Console to create a VPC with public and private subnets is much easier than creating them via CloudFormation, and Elastic Beanstalk supports ASP.NET application deployment automatically. EB uses a CloudFormation template to manage its own resources and can be customized later if needed.

Read through the [Launching an Elastic Beanstalk Application in a VPC with Bastion Hosts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-bastion-host.html), [Launching an Elastic Beanstalk in a VPC with Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html) and [How to Deploy a .NET Sample Application Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html) examples, which should get you started. Your requirements are all covered by some combination of the steps listed in those three examples.

Once you've become familiar with how to use Elastic Beanstalk to configure and deploy your application package, you can also look into managing your Elastic Beanstalk environment from a CloudFormation template, to automate the full process. See [Elastic Beanstalk Template Snippets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html) for getting started with this step.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing info. i will be directly running it through cloudformation. what excetly i am looking for is to have above configuration with endpoint (my website which will be in s3) . i have tried through console but that is not helping me here. my cloudformation is failing on wait condition (which is setting up autoscaling).. i have to find someway to configure the whole application. i have allready gone through the links but somewhere it is not working out. that's why i was asking for cloudformation template.

Comment: I think your question may be too broad in its current form- please add details to your question to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs, and also ask multiple questions for multiple specific issues you might have. See [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details.